How to lock a cell after entering a date in Excel
I’ve tried most of the solutions I found online, but none of them seem to work for me. What I need is for any user to enter a date, and after that, the cell should be locked from any further edits or deletion. This needs to be applied only to column C.
The issue I'm facing is that either the solutions I tried lock the cells completely and prevent me from entering data, or the code simply doesn’t work.

The below will lock column C once data has been entered into it however it will leave the other columns unlocked (until Z, but this can be changed to what columns you are using).
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="{PASSWORD}"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B,D:Z").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="{PASSWORD}"
    End If
End Sub


I want to select a specific column, not all columns.

You could add If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then

Are you looking for the whole worksheet to be locked once something is entered into the C column or only the C column to be locked?

only the C column to be locked

After writing the code, how will I run and save it?
I get this message "The following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks: • VB project To save a file with these features, click No, and then choose a macro-enabled file type in the File Type list. To continue saving as a macro-free workbook, dick Yes."

By saving the file as a macro-enabled file (.xlsm)

I have edited the answer to keep the other columns unlocked once data has been entered into column C. Let me know how it goes.

In the new code I get an error "run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"
Do I need to do anything before writing the code in view code? It's a new experience for me that I've never done before.

Could you please explain if there's anything I need to do before writing the code to make it work?

What is your sheet called. The default is Sheet1 (as in the code) so you will need to change this if the sheet name is different. I have ran this on a fresh install and fresh sheet and works no problem so no additional things needed apart from developer enabled which you already have if you can add VBA.

Do I need to make changes to the cell format, such as turning off lockup? before writing the code

No changes to the cell format was made testing this.
